# Append something as nth child - If only child append as first child

Tags: jquery

How can I append something as the `nth child` of a div with id `'selected_panel'`

- As nth child.
- If there are no children append as first child(simply prepend).
- The children of the 'selected_panel' could be anything from `div` to
  `label` or they might be a `span`.

i.e: I don't know which types of HTML elements will be the children so i cannot really use something like:

```
// This looks only for children with type ''div''
$("#selected_panel div:nth-child(1)")
```

Comment: you can find more information here 
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/  
http://api.jquery.com/?s=nth-child

Comment: Already read that, I doubt I would take the time to try and ask the question without reading through that first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Lp9kngp0/3/ every third child is selected whether it is div label span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create plugin:

```js
$.fn.nthorfirst = function (path, i) {
    var elems = this.find(path);
    if (elems.length > i) return elems.eq(i);
    else return this;
}

$('#selected_panel').nthorfirst('> *', 2).before("<div> Done! </div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selected_panel">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <div>Lipsum</div>
    <a href="#"> Dolor </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ':nth-child(1)` without any tags.

```
$("#selected_panel :nth-child(1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var e = $('<div>New Child</div>'); //New child to be added
    var c = $('#selected_panel').children(); //gets the children of div
    if (c.length) {                         //if there are children inside the div
        var l = c.length;
        $('#selected_panel>*:nth-child(' + l + ')').after(e);
    } else {                                //if there is no child
        $('#selected_panel').append(e);
    }
});
```

You can change the value of `l` according to the position where you want to append the new child.

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div id="selected_panel">
    <div>AADsd</div>
    <div>AADssdd</div>
    <div>asdfAADsd</div>
    <div>AADssdd</div>
    <div>AADsdsd</div> <span>sdfsadfsa</span>
 <span>sert3dfsadfsa</span>
 <span>s457647dfsadfsa</span>

    <p>er</p>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/350/

Answer (score 1):

This will insert an element as the `nth` child if there are at least `n-1` elements, else it will be inserted at the end.

```
var n = 7;
var len = $("#selected_panel").children().length;
var index = (len >= n) ? n-1 : len;
$("#selected_panel").find(':nth-child(' + index + ')').after($('<div>bar</div>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtr2wd7b/1/

Comment: where 'n' is the position I want to append?